# A "false" Lax-Milgram proof

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

A correct proof of the Law-Milgram Theorem using the Banach-Fixed Point Theorem could be found [here](http://jones.math.unibas.ch/~beilina/CDE/Lectures/Lecture5.pdf) on slide 10 onwards. I have another proof, which must be false, but I cannot see the fault...

Let $V$ be a vector space with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and induced norm $\|u\| := \sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle}$ and $a : V\times V \to V$ a bounded bilinear form, i.e. there exists some $C > $ such that $|a(u,v)| \le C\|u\|\|v\|$.

For $v \in V$ define a linear map $(Av)(u) := a(v,u)$. Then by Riesz representation theorem there exists a unique $\tau Av$ such that for all $u \in V$ we have
$$
 \langle \tau Av, u \rangle = (Av)(u)
$$
and this correspondence is linear in $u$ and in $v$ and isometric. So we have

1) $\|\tau Av\| = \|Av\|$ because the ''Riesz correspondence'' is isometric,

2) $\|Av\| \le C\|v\|$ because $(Av)u = a(v,u) \le C\|v\|\|u\|$.

Then I want to show that there exists some $\varepsilon$ such that the map
$$
 T_{\varepsilon}u := u - \varepsilon(\tau Au - f)
$$
(where $f$ is the ''Riesz'' representant of some given linear functional $F : V\to V$)
is a contraction mapping. For this
\begin{align*}
 \| T_{\varepsilon}u - T_{\varepsilon}v \| & = \| (u-v) - \varepsilon( \tau Au - \tau Av ) \| \\
               & = \| (u-v) - \varepsilon( \tau A(u-v) ) \| \\
               & \le \| (u-v) \| + \varepsilon \|\tau A(u-v) \| \\
               & = \| (u-v) \| + \varepsilon \|A(u-v)\| \\
               & \le \| (u-v) \| + \varepsilon C\|u-v\| \\
               & = (1+\varepsilon C)\|u-v\|
\end{align*}
so each $\varepsilon < 0$ would work, but this result is false (see for example the correct proof in the slides, and btw that $a$ must be coercive was not required in my arguments), but I cannot see what went wrong in the argumentation, I just used valid equations for the norms and so on? Can you help me finding my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assumed $\epsilon>0$ when you took $\epsilon$ outside of the norm. It should really be $|\epsilon|\,.$ This would give $\|Tu-Tv\|\le (1+|\epsilon|C)\|u-v\|\,.$

Comment: Oh my god, such a stupid fault, and I starred on it thinking something with the norms in the different spaces went wrong... thank you!